# If I download Mist 0.8.1 to a new Windows machine, will it do a fast sync on geth automatically after I set the machine to connect to the ETC chain?

Tags: mist, blockchain

Alternatively, with Mist 0.8.1 on Windows, will I need to configure it a particular way to get it to do the faster initial sync of the blockchain?

Or will it fast sync automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download Ethereum Wallet [0.8.1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.1) to use the wallet on the Classic chain.

Note that Ethereum Wallet [0.8.2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.2) will NOT run on the Classic chain but instead prompts you to download the tools from https://ethereumclassic.github.io.

When you start Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1, it will ask you "Do you want to activate the chain in which funds linked to the exploit are restored to a contract where they can be withdrawn by The DAO token holders?". Answer **No** to use Ethereum Wallet on the Classic chain. Ethereum Wallet will then instruct the packaged `geth` executable to download the Classic chain with the `--fast` automatically.